# Splash screen for android auto (head unit)

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-auto

How is it possible to create a splash screen for android auto to display it on a head unit of a car? I wish it would be a logo of a company or user greeting in full screen. By the ideal it could be with some animation. So how can I deal with splash screen implementation for android auto?

Answer (score 0):

please follow the [steps](https://medium.com/geekculture/implementing-the-perfect-splash-screen-in-android-295de045a8dc)

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
            //This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
           Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
           finish();
           }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Create Background for Splash Screen in drawable/`splash_background.xml`, the bitmap is the image we want to show.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="<http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_gradient"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_fg"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Create the gradient onto which your app logo will be placed in drawable/`bg_gradient.xml`, background can be a gradient or any colour depending on your app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="<http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="135"
        android:startColor="#ff1b49"
        android:endColor="#e67d20" />
</shape>
```

Setting the Intent to your MainActivity.java from `SplashScreenActivity.java`

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Android Auto does not have such things like activities or layout files, so I'm afraid this approach is not answering the question above.